# Query using running total in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to run a similar query using hibernate. I am concerned because if i set `@runtot as 0`,another query running at the same time might get wrong result.

`SET @runtot:=0; 
select name, quantity, (@runtot := @runtot + quantity) as runtotal from item where @runtot+quantity <= 20;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under expected usage, that won't be a problem.

Your variable `@runtot` is associated to a specific database session which has a 1-to-1 relation to a specific JDBC `Connection` with your database.  The Hibernate `Session` and `EntityManager` objects are also associated with a specific JDBC `Connection` at any given moment in time too.

Given that neither `Session` or `EntityManager` are thread-safe, it's implied that you should never be in a situation where the same `Connection` is executing your example code more than once causing the variable's state to be tainted.

So as long as you never share `Session` and `EntityManager` between threads of execution, your code will work just fine without any fear of another execution creating problems.